# How to pass JSON via ajax to PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to pass a json string to php via ajax and php is not decoding it properly.  a vardump in php after the decode always returns null. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Big thanks!!!

```
var addObj= {"facility":"Baptist Medical Center",
     "osb":"Jacksonville",
     "office":"North Branch"};

var JSONstr = JSON.stringify(addObj);

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    var rt = xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert(rt);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","jsontest.php?addObj="+JSONstr,true);
xmlhttp.send();

//php code in jsontest.php
<?php
var_dump(json_decode($_GET['addObj'], true));
?>

//php returns null
```

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['addObj']`? echo it first.

Comment: why not use jQuery's ajax()? Also I suggest using POST rather than GET in your request. GETs tend to be cached.

Comment: echo $_GET['addObj'];

 //results
 {"facility":"Baptist Medical Center","osb":"Jacksonville","office":"North Branch"}0.624341037357226

Comment: what's the '0.624341037357226' bit about?  that's not valid JSON. http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try `urldecode`ing the parameter first:

```
var_dump(json_decode(urldecode($_GET['addObj']), true));
```

Comment: @Neal Using the `GET` method the string probably gets encoded, since it contains whitespace.